# How to trigger Google Script when a Google Task is marked "completed"

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-tasks-api

Google Apps Script allows scripts to be triggered by a variety of events; see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

I'd like to update the tag on an email (in Gmail) when the user marks a task completed (in Google Tasks) but there doesn't seem to be a trigger for this.

However, Zapier is able to trigger on these events somehow:
[supported triggers](https://zapier.com/help/google-tasks/#supported-triggers)

So it seems like this trigger must exist.

Is there a way to do this other than using Zapier?

Unfortunately Zapier (in addition to costing money) only allows you to add tags to Gmail messages, not remove them -- so one can't (for instance) change a message tag from [uncompleted-task] to [completed-task].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this writing (2018-05-15), Google Apps Script does not support a trigger to track a task's status.

I suspect that Zapier is polling the status of the task via the Task API; ie. periodically checking the status property of the task and firing an event once the status changes to complete.

You can do the same (with time-based triggers) using the Task API as an Advanced Service in GAS:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tasks
- https://developers.google.com/tasks/quickstart/apps-script

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I created a test of this in Zapier and can confirm that they are polling the Google Tasks API every 5 minutes (!) for this -- so I can implement that myself on a more sane interval.